# Rails: cannot load such file - spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through chapter 9 of Hartl's rails tutorial.  I just added some tests for the 'edit' page, but it won't run on the command line.

I'm trying to run 'bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"'

I think there may be a problem with my user_pages_spec.rb . I might have too many 'end' at the bottom.

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_page_spec.rb -e "edit p
age"
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec
/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Sites/sample_a
pp/spec/requests/user_page_spec.rb (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.1
3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.1
3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.1
3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.1
3.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.1
3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.1
3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end      
  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
 end
 end
end
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  # gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you're executing the wrong file:

Change this:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_page_spec.rb -e "edit p
age"
```

To:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit p
age"
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
```

as your file is `user_pages_spec.rb`